# How to enclose a ball more than once with a surface homeomorphic to $S^2$? In 3D.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-topology, quantum-field-theory

In 3 dimensional space, how to enclose a monopole (either point-like or ball-like, both types exist.) more than once with a surface homeomorphic to $S^2$?

Comment: Level surfaces of the distance function?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is a monopole? What does it mean to enclose it more than once with a surface?

Comment: Thanks for you attention! What I mean is just a point or a little ordinary 3-ball. This has a physics origin in the study of magnetic monopole.

Comment: @sfman: Thanks! I still don't know what you mean by enclosing more than once. Do you mean several concentric spheres, as the answer below interprets, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Maybe not. Please see my comment under that answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is a three-manifold and $B$ is a (smoothly embedded, tame) three-ball in $M$, then just take level surfaces of the distance function from $B$. That is, take the surfaces 
$$S_\epsilon = \{p\in M\ |\ d(p,B) = \epsilon\}.$$

For small $\epsilon$, all $S_\epsilon$ will be diffeomorphic to $\partial B = S^2$.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I don't mean level surfaces. Maybe something like this mapping $(\sin\theta \cos n\phi, \sin\theta\sin n\phi, \cos\theta)$, but could it be more bizarre or interesting?

Comment: @huotuichang I'm not sure what you mean. If you have a surface homeomorphic to $S^2$, it can always be described as level surface of a map.